# getting IllegalStateException in spring afterTestClass

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spock, spring-test

getting IllegalStateException when I run my integrationTest.

below is my test class:

```
@ActiveProfiles("local")
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = RANDOM_PORT, classes = [DemoApplication])
class ApplicationIT extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    ApplicationContext applicationContext

    def "check applicationContext"() {
        expect:
        applicationContext
    }
}
```

this class running fine.

when I extend this in other class and trying to make service calls. then it's failing.

```
class TrainServiceTest extends ApplicationIT {

    @Autowired
    TrainService trainService

    @Autowired
    TrainClient trainClient

    def "verify trainClient"() {
        given:
        def paymentDetail = createPaymentDetail()

        when:
        def sessionId = trainClient.getTrainTranscation(paymentDetail)
        def result = trainService.getTranscationDetails(sessionId)

        then:
        result.firstName == 'test'
        result.lastName == 'lname'
        result.city == 'city'
    }
}
```

when I run this in debug mode, all the assertions happening in then block.

finally, call happened to class `org.spockframework.spring.SpringInterceptor` and method is `public void interceptCleanupSpecMethod(IMethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable` and in this method failing statement is  `manager.afterTestClass();`

getting below error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The ApplicationContext loaded for [[WebMergedContextConfiguration@51c80219 testClass = TrainServiceTest, locations = '{}', classes = '{class com.test.DemoApplication}', contextInitializerClasses = '[]', activeProfiles = '{local}', propertySourceLocations = '{}', propertySourceProperties = '{org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper=true, server.port=0}', contextCustomizers = set[org.spockframework.spring.mock.SpockContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.actuate.metrics.MetricsExportContextCustomizerFactory$DisableMetricExportContextCustomizer@22c86919, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.properties.PropertyMappingContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebDriverContextCustomizerFactory$Customizer@21ec5d87, org.springframework.boot.test.context.filter.ExcludeFilterContextCustomizer@363f6148, org.springframework.boot.test.json.DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizerFactory$DuplicateJsonObjectContextCustomizer@138fe6ec, org.springframework.boot.test.mock.mockito.MockitoContextCustomizer@0, org.springframework.boot.test.web.client.TestRestTemplateContextCustomizer@2e5c7f0b, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestArgs@1, org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestWebEnvironment@57c758ac], resourceBasePath = 'src/main/webapp', contextLoader = 'org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader', parent = [null]]] is not active. This may be due to one of the following reasons: 1) the context was closed programmatically by user code; 2) the context was closed during parallel test execution either according to @DirtiesContext semantics or due to automatic eviction from the ContextCache due to a maximum cache size policy.
```